# How to configure IIS7 to allow zip file uploads using classic asp?

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

I recently installed Windows 2008 Server to replace a crashed hard drive on a web server with a variety of web pages including several classic ASP applications. One of these makes extensive use of file uploads using a com tool that has worked for several years.

More information:

My users did not provide good information in that very small zips (65K) work once I tested it myself, but larger ones do not. I did not test for the cut-off, but 365K fails. And it is not only zip files after all. A 700K doc file failed also. ErrorCode 800a0035.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a size limit that you will probably need to set - what's the 500 error?

Answer (score 1):

Soneone named Anthony Jones in microsoft.public.inetserver.asp.general provided the answer as follows:

> In IIS7 IIS manager click in the web
>   site and double click the ASP icon in 
>   the features view.  Expand Limits
>   Properties and modify the Maximum 
>   Requesting Entity Body Limit.

To which I replied:

That did the trick. And it was so easy. You have no idea how many things I tried that did not work.

I think there may be a second part though. One of the things I had done was to change the

setting in applicationhost.config from:

```
    <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
        <section name="asp" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

to

```
        <section name="asp" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

After I made your change and tested it, I changed the above to Deny just on general principals of not fixing what was not broken. The website immediately stopped working until I changed it back to Allow.